# ERROR: Unable to open datasource with ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I am trying to convert OpenDrive file `xodr` file format to shapefile format `shp` using gr2ogr

I am using:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" Town_01.shp Town01.xodr
```

But I get the following error and I dont know why:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `Town01.xodr' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
```

Comment: what is an `xodr` file? should `ogr2ogr` recognise it?

Comment: Its an OpenDrive file

Comment: You can try to convert it first to OSM: https://github.com/tiev-tongji/xodr-OSM-Converter

Answer (score 3):

XODR is not a supported file type.  [See here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) for a list of supported vector file formats.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in 2023 with DLR's fork of GDAL:

https://github.com/DLR-TS/gdal

ref:

- https://talks.osgeo.org/foss4g-2023/talk/9KCVBK/
- https://github.com/DLR-TS/gdal/blob/92381f15e89c4320927cf14ce5411c51a986bc34/doc/source/drivers/vector/xodr.rst

at the time of writing, this feature has not yet been merged into GDAL official repo